# Why does pivotal cloud foundry does not remove a route when a corresponding app is deleted?

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have been exploring Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Public Cloud Version by setting up an Pivotal Web Services account. 
While exploring the CF CLI I followed the below tutorial.
https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry/introduction

I was able to successfully push the sample spring boot app to PCF Cloud and follow the tutorial.

When I started to play around with it, I tried deleting the app using the below command. cf-spring is my app name.

cf delete cf-spring
[image: CF Delete Command]

When navigated to my Pivotal Web Service account, I could see the app has been deleted. The route still displays the name of the route which was created when an app was created using the cf push command.

[image: Pivotal DashBoard]

So I tried to delete the route using the below command. 
[image: Delete Route]

It does not allow me to delete using CLI ? Does the app delete command should have taken care to remove the related routes associated with the application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `cf delete-route -h` to see the syntax of the delete-route command.

You probably want to run `cf delete-route cfapps.io --hostname cf-spring-rested-platypus`.

In recent versions of cf-cli you can also run `cf delete-orphaned-routes`.

I *think* the reason CF doesn't completely delete the route when you delete an app is so that it kind of keeps the hostname reserved for your use, ie: someone else can't reuse it in another org or space if you've just taken down your app for a refresh. It's kind of annoying when you actually want to reuse the hostname in another space, but considering the multi-tenancy capabilities it kind of makes sense to keep them intact/reserved.

Answer (score 0):

`cf delete APP_NAME` will not delete the route bound to the Apps and this should not happen first-of-all. Because the router-concept in Cloud foundry is that

> One App can have Multiple Routes and Multiple Routes can be configured to one App.

Its **Many-to-One mapping.** So there is a possibility that the routes you created would still be mapped to another App and it would be as Orphaned-route, only when there are no apps for that routes..

So its a cautious decision and a wise decision too !!